# Chrome Browser with localhost

Tags: reactjs, mern

Testing an e-commerce website, it's MERN stack when I run npm run develop chrome opens the page on localhost but I'm unable to click anything on it.

I open Microsoft Edge go in the localhost the application works properly, can add to cart, go into payment, everything works.

Was there an update on Chrome and how I fix this issue

Works on Microsoft Edge not on Chrome

Comment: Assuming you’re on the latest version of chrome, does it work as expected in chrome when you’re in incognito mode? If so, it might be a browser extension you’re using. Or something in your code that depends on browser storage, but maybe there isn’t logic to handle what should happen if that data isn’t formatted as expected.

Comment: There’s nothing here anyone can use to help.

Comment: Yes on the latest Chrome version, okay could  be the storage. the code is good since it works on Microsoft Edge

Comment: Ceckenrode it worked clearly the cahe lol, something so simple..Thanks